# Matlab Error Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced

Tags: matlab

Hello i get this error when i run the program I think it is from  e (exponent)
the question is
Show that the function f(x) = e^x −(x^2/2) -x -1
 has zero of multiplicity 3 at α = 0
and then, find the approximate solution of the zero of the function with the help
of the Newton’s method, first and second modified Newton’s methods, by taking
initial approximation x0 = 1.5 within an accuracy of 10^−4
.

```
    function sol=newton(fn,dfn,x0,tol)
    old=x0+1;
    while abs(x0-old)>tol
    old=x0;
    x0=old-feval(fn,old)/feval(dfn,old)
    end
    sol=x0;
```

I typed this
fn = @(x) e^x -(x^2/2) -x -1
and the other inputs
i got the error on the title

Comment: Please include the complete error message and the complete code you use to call the function. At least `dfn` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the `e`.  Replace the `e` with `exp` for the exponential operator.

```
fn = @(x) exp(x) -(x^2/2) -x -1;
```

FWIW, the derivative of the above function `dfn` is:

```
dfn = @(x) exp(x) - x - 1;
```

Comment: To expand this answer: `e` can be interpreted to mean the scientific notation `1.0e1`. This is why MATLAB sometimes gives vague errors with `e` involved.

Comment: @sanchises - That's a very good point. I'll add an edit. Thanks.